# How can redis dump to several files but not only one？

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Hello，I'd like to ask you two questions. (I am using java and jedis)

1. I want to write 2G data to redis, how can I write faster?
2. Does the redis dump the data to several files, not only the dump.rdb? Such as the data is too large as 4G, the data will be dumped to the dump.rdb and dump2.rdb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import data faster into Redis by using variadic parameters commands (such as MSET), and/or using pipelining (which is supporting by Jedis) to aggregate roundtrips to the Redis instance. The less roundtrips, the faster import.

Another good practice is to deactivate the AOF (if it is activated), and background RDB dump (if it is activated) during the import operation (and reactivate them after).

Redis cannot dump to several data files. But if you write 2 GB of data in Redis, there is no way the dump file can take 4 GB. The dump file is always much more compact than the data in memory. The only way to get several dump files is to start multiple Redis instances and shard the data.

Comment: I set the redis maxmemory as 1KB，and when i import 10,000,000 datas to redis,the dump.rdb is 293MB.then i continued to import 10,000,000 datas to redis,the dump.rdb is still 293MB. However,i just could get all data i had imported.So,Where the 20,000,000 data were stored? I am so puzzled!

Comment: And the 2nd Problem.If i set the maxmemory as 1GB.And i want to write 1000GB of data in redis.what will happens?

Comment: The behavior also depends on the maxmemory-policy setting. The default is volatile-lru, but perhaps you have changed it. If you set 1 GB in maxmemory, with volatile-lru policy, Redis will start rejecting your write operations after 1 GB of data has been stored. Redis is an in-memory store. If you want to store more data than you have memory, use something else.